# How to change pop up icon in a pop up window in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to change the icon of pop up window from default browser icon in asp.net. In the below screen shot I have marked the icon.

[image]

Please let me know the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

it's called a favicon. just change your shortcut icon like so in the head of your html

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="http://path/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

they are usually quite small - no bigger than 50x50 px

Comment: This works when my application is on normal browser. But when i am opening my whole application as a pop up then it is not coming as per the screen shot. Please share your comment on this.

Comment: @TripatiSubudhi I'm afraid I don't know about that - did you put in runat = "server" ?

Comment: Have a look in the Shared folder in the Solution Explorer. You will see the_Layout.cshtml. you can probably change it in there

Comment: Sorry to say you, I am unable to find this in my Solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

To change the favicon for a website add this code in the `<head>` tag of the masterpage..

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```